# I want know that if two extension are enabled the which one will magento use?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I enabled two extensions for mail sending but don't know which one is used by magento each time.

Comment: Chances are that neither works correctly if they are conflicting. Not answerable without more information.

Answer (score 4):

send an email and add a debug code in each one of the extensions to see which one is uses.
You can add this line in both methods that send the email:

```
Mage::log('[Extension name here]', null, 'emails.log', true);
```

and then look in the `var/log/emails.log` file to see what is logged.

Comment: thanks Marius for guide...Can I manage in admin panel while sending the mail that which one should use for this mail..

Comment: I have no idea. you asked how you can identify which one is used, I answered. It totally depends on how the extensions are built, but most probably you won't be able to decide just from the admin panel.